# Google Sheets: How To Open File Offline

Tags: google-sheets, offline

So far I've followed the instructions for making files (Sheets etc) available offline using Chrome, but NOWHERE have I found anything on how to actually open and work on a file when offline.

I must be missing something obvious?  Any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

If you already activated offline access and selected the desired Sheets files, then you only have to open your Chrome browser (from an offline device) and select one of the offline files. Check the [offline guide](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6388102) for a deeper step by step documentation. Please leave a comment if you have doubts about this approach.